# In the name (what they're called)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

### I'm looking for a 4-word phrase. Can you tell me what it is?

---

[image]

```
  E H O F O G
  T O E N O N
  A M R V I P 
  D Y E G A S
  A F T H R T
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it:

> PARTS OF THE DAY?

Reasoning:
The top 4 images seem to depict

> MORNING, AFTERNOON (credit Stiv!), EVENING, and NIGHT, which we can find in the wordsearch by connecting adjacent letters:
>  [image: wordsearch]
>  The remaining unused letters (highlighted in yellow) can spell out the 4 word phrase PARTS OF THE DAY, which is what these four are called!

Comment: Not unused in rot13(NSGREABBA)!

Comment: Well done, that's the phrase I was looking for! rot13  (zl vqrn jnf gung lbh fubhyq pbaarpg gur hahfrq yrggref va pbeerpg beqre nyfb, whfg yvxr lbh qvq cerivbhfyl jvgu zbe.., nsg.. rgp. Naq gur gvgyr: "Va gur a=avtug, n=nsgreabba, z=zbeavat, r=riravat" (fb whfg abg va gur fnzr beqre nf gur vzntr bs gur chmmyr)